# how to filter out specific char(unicode like U+1F603 ) in a string in java

Tags: java, unicode, decode, unicode-string, unicode-escapes

I'd like to **filter out some char who's unicode somekind like U+1F603** with java lauguage.
They are all kinds of information in the string,only filter the specific char.How?Can any one help?
Thanks.

Comment: What did you mean by filter out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U+1F603 character can be written as `\uD83D\uDE03` in Java.

If you have your text in `String yourString` variable, following code should remove occurrences of the special character.

```
yourString.replace("\uD83D\uDE03", "");
```

Comment: What if there are lots chars to filter out,convert all to utf-8 first?

Comment: If you are trying to remove all characters outside the basic multilingual plane then replace everything in the range `[\uD800-\uDFFF]`. But why? What's the problem you are trying to address?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
"happy".replaceAll( "" , "" )
```

> happy

## Java source code supports Unicode

Your Java source code may contain any of the over 140,000 characters defined in Unicode. So you can have a string literal using any such character. No need for escaping.

Before Java 18, you may need to instruct your tooling to save your source code files as UTF-8. In Java 18 and later, the default character encoding is UTF-8 across all platforms, per [*JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/400).

Your target, U+1F603, is , SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH.

```
String result = input.replaceAll( "" , "" ) ;  // Replacing target character with empty string, effectively a "remove all" operation.
```

Example:

```
System.out.println(
    "happy".replaceAll( "" , "" ) 
);
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/1cPi5V).

> happy

## Code points

To work with individual characters in Java, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

The Unicode Consortium has assigned a permanent identifier number to virtually every known character of every language and script. Currently the count of characters is over 140,000. The assigned numbers range from zero to just over a million. Obviously most of that number range is unassigned, reserved for private use or future use.

You want to remove , U+1F603, SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH.

Say we also want to remove also:

- , U+1F626, FROWNING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH
- , U+1F637, FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK

Make a list of those characters.

```
String forbidden = "";
List< Integer > forbiddenCodePoints = forbidden.codePoints().boxed().toList() ;
```

Get a stream of the code points assigned to each character of your input stream.

```java
String input = "happy  sad ";
IntStream codePoints = input.codePoints();
```

Filter those to eliminate any found in our list of forbidden code point numbers. For the code point `int` numbers that pass our test, append each to a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Lastly, build a `String` object from that `StringBuilder`.

```java
String result =
        codePoints
                .filter( codePoint -> ! forbiddenCodePoints.contains( codePoint ) )
                .collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append )
                .toString();
```

When run.

```
result = happy  sad
```

Here is alternative, for a one-liner, using [`IntStream#anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.IntPredicate)).

```java
System.out.println(
        "happy  sad "
                .codePoints()
                .filter( codePoint -> ! "".codePoints().anyMatch(  x -> x == codePoint) )
                .collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint , StringBuilder :: append )
                .toString()
);
```

When run.

```
happy  sad
```